# What are the total amount of resonance structures for these two cations and which is the most stable cation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, resonance, carbocation

Please see the following two cations. 
[image]

I have proposed the following resonance structures.

Please let me know if I have missed something.

Thank you.

[image]